# How to load existing chrome profile using watir?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, watir

i am trying to load existing chrome browser using watir. As you know, in my current chrome, i've login on facebook and another social media. But when i try to load facebook using chrome which is run by watir, facebook page still asking me to login. Here is my code:

```
 def test
    prefs = {
        download: {
          prompt_for_download: false,
          default_directory: '/Users/jaisanasrulloh/Downloads'
        }
      }
    args = ['user-data-dir=~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome']
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome,options: {prefs: prefs, args: args}
    browser.goto 'https://www.facebook.com/'
    sleep 10
    puts browser.title
    browser.close
end
```

anyone here knows how to load current caches in my current chrome into new chrome run by watir ?

Comment: Have you tried logging in using watir? Find the inputs, fill them, find the submit button and click it. Maybe it works.

Comment: You can set the user-data-dir value (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-chromeOptions-object). You can see examples of using Options with Watir here: http://watir.com/guides/chrome/